# Table top-row filtering

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I was asked to add filtering capability to b-table. I am providing it using top-row slot, but I would like to be able to control to which columns it applies (users do not want last column to be filterable - there should not be a input box for it). Is it possible to exclude it?

[image]

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Not the most pretty solution, but you could duplicate your td and use a v-if to decide which one should be shown (or a JS filter on fields to create two kinds of fields). OR use :disabled="" and a condition to disable the input you want :)

Comment: Please post your code as a formatted codeblock, not as an image

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Wimanicesir for input!
I was able to solve this myself. In order to exclude one of the columns, you need to use v-if command like below:

[image]

[image]